# XML transformation using XSLT doesn't work

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am in phase of learning XSLT,

Following is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <catalog>
     <cd>
      <title>xyz</title>
      <artist>pqr</artist>
      <country>USA</country>
     </cd>
      <cd>
      <title>abc</title>
      <artist>def</artist>
      <country>France</country>
     </cd>

</catalog>
```

Output Expected

```
  Title |Artist |Country
  xyz |pqr |USA
  abc |def |France
```

My First attempt is to read the title.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="title">
   <xsl:value-of select="catalog/cd/title"/>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the display is

```
      pqr 
      USA
     
      
      
      def
      France
```

I am just trying to read the title here. Don't understand what is wrong .
I am sure I have to use looping and concatenation to achieve the output.

Can someone help?

Thank you
Regards
Prat

---

Edit
New xml

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <multimap:Messages xmlns:multimap="http://sap.com/xi/XI/SplitAndMerge">
    <multimap:Message1>
     <Products>
      <Product>
        <OrderID>9000625868</OrderID>
      </Product>
     </Products>
</multimap:Message1>
<multimap:Message2>
 <CustomerOrderCollection>
    <CustomerOrder>
        <ZZCASE_KUT/>
        <DivisionCodeText>Test</DivisionCodeText>
        <ApprovalStatusCode/>
        <DateTime>2022-06-07T12:06:25.068</DateTime>
        <TaxAmount>0.000000</TaxAmount> 
    </CustomerOrder>
    <CustomerOrder>
        <ZZCASE_KUT/>
        <DivisionCodeText>Test2</DivisionCodeText>
        <ApprovalStatusCode/>
        <DateTime>2022-06-08T12:06:25.068</DateTime>
        <TaxAmount>10.000000</TaxAmount>    
    </CustomerOrder>
```

Output desired

```
   ZZCASE_KUT|DivisionCodeText|ApprovalStatusCode|DateTime|TaxAmount
    |Test||2022-06-07T12:06:25.068|0.000000
    |Test1||2022-06-08T12:06:25.068|10.000000
```

XSLT i used

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text" />

   <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="' |'"/>

   <xsl:template match="CustomerOrderCollection">
    <xsl:for-each select="CustomerOrder[1]/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            translate(substring(local-name(), 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') , 
            substring(local-name(), 2))"/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustomerOrder">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>  

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is very different form expected.

```
               9000625868
      
     


 ZZCASE_KUT |DivisionCodeText |ApprovalStatusCode |DateTime |TaxAmount
 |Test | |2022-06-07T12:06:25.068 |0.000000
 |Test2 | |2022-06-08T12:06:25.068 |10.000000
```

Version 3

```
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output method="text" />

     <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="' |'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/CustomerOrderCollection" />

     <xsl:for-each select="CustomerOrder[1]/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(
        translate(substring(local-name(), 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') , 
        substring(local-name(), 2))"/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CustomerOrder">
   <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
     |0E-14 | | |2022-06-07T12:06:25.068 |0.000000 | |1





    
        9000625868
    




     |0E-14 | | |2022-06-07T12:06:25.068 |0.000000 | |1
```

Comment: I think spending a few moments with an XSLT tutorial would greatly help you.

Comment: The key mistake here is that you need to understand the concept of the context item. In a template rule with `match='title'`, any relative path expressions select starting at the title, so to get the value of the title you want `select="."`, not `select="catalog/cd/title"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to know that there are [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#built-in-rule) that will be applied to the content. Unless you provide your own that override the default behavior, XSLT will match on any `node()` apply-templates to the children, and `text()` will return their value. Therefore, if all you did was execute the stylesheet, it will generate output will all of the `text()`.

Now, for your current template, you are matching on `title` elements, and then attempt to get the value-of with a relative XPath expression that is looking for `catalog/cd/title` that are children of the `title` (there are none, so it produces nothing. This has the effect of filtering out all of the matched `title`, rather than producing the desired output. If you wanted to select the value-of that `title`, you could select `.` (the context node).

To produce your desired output, you would want a stylesheet like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="' |'"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <xsl:for-each select="cd[1]/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                translate(substring(local-name(), 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') , 
                substring(local-name(), 2))"/>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your second XML, you could add a template matching the root node, and push the `CustomerOrderCollection`, bypassing all of the built-in template rules that would be processing those multimap elements before they hit on `CustomerOrderCollection`:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/CustomerOrderCollection" />
</xsl:template>
```

You could further consolidate and avoid some duplication by using named templates and modes, but this demonstrates one way to achieve the desired output.

Comment: I cannot understand why you are willing to hardcode the names of the `catalog` and `cd` elements, but then go to such great lengths to avoid a simple `<xsl:text>Title |Artist |Country&#10;</xsl:text>`.

Comment: Just demonstrating how to transform things

Comment: Columns are more likely to vary in the data than the document element or cd rows elements also.

Comment: Hi @MadsHansen I finding an issue with different XML. Can you please explain ? Thank you Regards

Comment: The `multimap:Message1` is being processed by those built-in templates, so it's `OrderID/text()` is bleeding through. You can bypass and start processing at the `CustomerOrderCollection` by defining a template on the root node and pushing the CustomerOrderCollection: `<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/CustomerOrderCollection" />
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: @MadsHansen : I tried , the output is very different . I have edited the new xslt . Please guide. Thank you Regards

Comment: You didn't add that root node template, you merged it with the other catalog template.